# How to get title by xpath?

Tags: java, xpath, selenium

Is there any way to get title by xpath insted of `driver.getTitle()`

I tried the following:
`By.xpath("//title")`

but it did not work. For example StackOverflow

```
public class TestStack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//title")));

        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//title")).getText());
    }

}
```

Element by xpath is not found

Comment: give  the html please..

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to use `driver.getTitle()`?

Comment: I'd be interested in an answer to @Amey question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be browser-dependent. The following code produced correct output on FF 3.6 but failed to do so (empty string) in both IE 9 and Chrome 31.

```
WebElement title = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//title"));         
System.out.println(title.getText());
```

If you really don't want to use `getTitle()` this should work on any browser:

```
title.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not see a reason why you would not want to use `driver.getTitle()`

But if you must use xpath, you could do:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//title")).getText();
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the updated question seems, like the failure is at

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//title")));
```

To fix it, I would recommend waiting for a time longer than `0` seconds, and also change 
`visibilityOfElementLocated` to `presenceOfElementLocated`.

Ideally you should use `ExpectedConditions.titleIs()`
More info about the available options, can be found [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html).

Comment: OP have some hidden matter I think,as he is not using direct method..:)

Comment: another way is `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//title/text()"))` ... I know ruby where i could do like `driver.find_element("//title/text()").to_s`. I don't know the java equivalent one..

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not doing it. I have already tried it, please take a look at my updated question above where I try to get title from StackOverflow

Comment: What error do you get? I would wait for more time than `0` in `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 0);`

Comment: It is a typo, I have corrected it.  I am waiting 60 seconds: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60); and get the TimeoutException

Comment: Updated my answer, change `visibilityOfElementLocated` to `presenceOfElementLocated`.